# How to use QuantLib in C# easily?

Tags: quantlib

I am not good at environment setting. Sometimes I use QuantLib in Python. Now I am wondering if there is a instruction on how to use QuantLib in C#. I looked at the QuantLib web page, but there is not any instruction telling how to use... I am puzzled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8.5 with .Net framework 4.6.1:

Click Project => Manage NuGet Packages.  Select 'Browse' then search for Quantlib.  Several packages will be found.  QLNet is most popular, but I have used NQuantLib64 as well.  After it is installed, add a using statement at the top of your project with the rest of your using statements:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using QLNet;                  //If you choose QLNet
using QuantLib;               //If you choose NQuantLib64
```

That's it. Either QuantLib API is ready to be used.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow when I go back workplace. Thanks in advance.